# Gitlab pipeline with external dependency

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have 2 maven projects hosted on Gitlab. Let's call them A and B. Project A depends on project B.
I want to use gitlab-ci to build A.

Here is the gitlab-ci.yml file for project B:

```
image: maven:3-jdk-8

build:
  script: "mvn install -B"
```

What should the gitlab-ci in project A look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use GIT SUBMODULES with your project A to refer to project B and then add

```
GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
```

to the gitlab-ci.yml file in project A. Further project B needs also a CI configuration file in the project root.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/git_submodules.html